# C# RaisePropertyChanging?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm not sure why I should use [RaisePropertyChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging.propertychanging.aspx), when notifying the view fx:

```
 private LoggingLvl _myLoggingLvl;
    public LoggingLvl MyLoggingLvl
    {
        get { return _myLoggingLvl; }
        set
        {
            RaisePropertyChanging("MyLoggingLvl");
            _myLoggingLvl = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyLoggingLvl");
        }
    }
```

why is it recommended to use `RaisePropertyChanging`?

Comment: You tagged your question with "WPF" and "MVVM" but you are linking to `DataSet.RaisePropertyChanging` which has nothing to do with the interfaces `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging` that are typically used in ViewModels in a MVVM context. Are you sure your class derives from `DataSet`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: good spot!  I assumed he was referring to `INotifyPropertyChanging`/`INotifyPropertyChanged`...

Comment: @DanPuzey: I am pretty sure he did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `INotifyPropertyChanging` would allow consuming code a chance to consume the *previous* value of a property, before a change is applied.  This is not frequently going to be useful, but there are cases where it might be: if you imagine a property that represents an "active object," this event would allow you to trigger code that would fire when the object is de-activated.

As a contrived example, consider a UI where the change in value of a field is required to display in a specific way: the old value should "float" off the screen leaving the new value behind.  If a model class implemented `INotifyPropertyChanging`, a viewmodel class could attach to this event in order to cache the *old* value for use in the float animation.  This allows the model class to represent the current state, while the viewmodel can maintain all values necessary to drive the UI.

Answer (score 3):

I have never listened before that `RaisePropertyChanging` is *recommended*. You *can* use it if you need to notify to "outside world" that specified property *is going to changed*.

This can be useful, for example,  when some parts of your application should validate the changing property state against other parameters of your system, so may be also signal that it's not a subject to change, as following [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) your class may not be aware of states of other instances of types of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The INotifyPropertyChanging interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value is changing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging.aspx

assume for a long running validation task on your property. hope take 5 seconds for updating the property value. meanwhile some other property are are looking for it these properties are treated under race condition. and wait under a queue and one property changed notification done then the first object will get change to get or set the property value.

let me give you some examples.

Comment: No, you should never take 5 seconds to update a property value.